# Mock void methods, which change their argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have an interface, which looks something like this

```
public interface ParameterProvider
{
    void provideParameter(Map<String, String> parameters);
}
```

An instance of it is used in the method I want to write a unit test for:

```
@Override
public void process(...)
{
    ...
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameterProvider.provideParameter(parameters);
    ...
}
```

How can I mock the `ParameterProvider` to perform actions on the argument, that's passed to its `provideParameter`-method?

My first idea was to change the return type from `void` to `Map`and actually return the modified `Map` (which seems a lot nicer anyway). Then testing is no problem:

```
when(parameterProvider.provideParameter(anyMap())).thenReturn(MY_PARAMETERS);
```

However since the interface is used in a framework, which for some odd reason seems to require the methods to be void, this is not an option right now.

Is there a way to still mock this thing. I'm using Mockito, but I don't need to stick with it, if there are other mocking frameworks to get the job done.

**EDIT**:
I also tried to use `doAnwser`, but I don't see how to modify the argument passed to the method:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        args[0] // that's the argument I want to modify
        return null;
    }})
.when(parameterProvider).provideParameter(anyMap());
```

Comment: Can you do it manually, without a mocking framework?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Mockito.doAnswer()](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer%28org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29) will allow you to mock void methods and manipulate the parameters passed to it via your own closure/class implementing [Answer](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) (provided your parameters are *mutable*, obviously).

So given your code:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        args[0] // that's the argument I want to modify
        return null;
    }})
 .when(parameterProvider).provideParameter(anyMap());
```

args[0] would be a Map (inspect via a debugger) and assuming it's mutable, you should be able to populate/change it within your anonymous class e.g.

```
((Map)args[0]).put(x, y);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? I can get the argument, which is passed to the method, but I don't see how to modify it. I added my code to the original question.